No matching version found for package version that that exists on npmjs.com
I am attempting to install @solana-developers/helpers@2.5.4. This package version exists and is on https://www.npmjs.com/package/@solana-developers/helpers
% npm i
npm error code ETARGET
npm error notarget No matching version found for @solana-developers/helpers@^2.5.4.
npm error notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm error notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2024-09-05T20_12_13_318Z-debug-0.log

Why is the npm command line application telling me the version does not exist? How can I install it?

This was just latency - while the https://npmjs.com UI showed the new package immediately, it took around 10 mins for the package to be available on the command line npm.
